# C++0x specification in HTML or ePub for Kindle?

Tags: c++11

Is the C++0x specification (FCD) available in HTML or ePub form for reading on a Kindle?

Comment: Don't you need MobiPocket format on a Kindle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting PDF files to Kindle 3 format (.prc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528783/converting-pdf-files-to-kindle-3-format-prc)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything official. Can you download [the original PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) and convert it using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)?

Comment: Converting PDFs is generally a lose.

Comment: The linked document N3092 (March 2010) is not the latest draft. N3292 isn't publicly available any more from ISO since mid of May after becoming Final Draft. You have two options: wait for bying the standard from ISO or reading an older draft like N3242, but beware: some things changed during the Madrid 2011 meeting.

Answer (score 0):

It's only available as PDF and has been obsoleted by the [full specification](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372), also PDF. You will [need a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528783/converting-pdf-files-to-kindle-3-format-prc).