# Converting PDF files to Kindle 3 format (.prc)

Tags: pdf, kindle

I am trying to convert this pdf file (http://www.filedropper.com/freewill) to kindle format (.prc).

I use Mobipocket Creator and build the pdf file, and then put the generated .prc file on my kindle, however it still shows up as PDF images and not kindle text, so I can't re-size the text.

Does anyone know how I can make that PDF file be in a format that kindle can re-size the text?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure how this Is a programming question...

Comment: How are you calling the mobipocket creator API? You'll have to show us your source for us to have any chance of helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is frustrating to reflow PDF. Results are always unpredictable. On the other hand, PDF cropping tools like [briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) are quite effective, if you are trying to read it on a 6 inch device.

When it comes to converting an ebook, it is best to work with the text / HTML and try to convert that to an epub / mobi / .prc. [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is your friend there.

Comment: +1 for briss, excellent software.